# Unknown indoor plant; I.D. and repot?

Tags: identification, indoors, repotting

**Question 1:**
What is the name of this plant?

**Question 2:**
Should I separate & replant individual stalks?

[image: Full plant]
[image: Large Leaf; no sign of splitting]
[image: One large stalk with a single root. Stalk is smaller in size at ground level and increases in side with additional leafs]

*Thank you*

Comment: @TheGrumpyTurtle You need to create two separate questions if you have two questions. I recommend using this for the ID (edit the second question out), and creating a new question for the one about whether to separate them. You'll probably get more upvotes afterward (and potentially double for having two questions).

Comment: Yes, a philodendron.  This is a plant that wants to get big.  If you intend to keep it for a while have some space for it to grow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe your plant is a Philodendron but a young *Monstera deliciosa*. They're sometimes erroneously called a split-leaf Philodendron. The real split-leaf Philodendron is *Philodendron bipinnatifidum* as seen in this photo. [image]

Another common name for *Monstera deliciosa* is Swiss cheese plant referring to the cut-out nature of the leaves. Yours doesn't show any yet but as it grows, new leaves will start showing fenestration leaves (meaning large cut out sections). When the plant is still young, the leaves are intact and smaller. I know the leaf you're holding looks big but they can get huge - up to one metre (3 feet) long. The plant forms a vine and in its natural habitat can grow 20 metres (66 feet) high, although happily, yours will never get that big! You can see why it got called Monstera.

[image]

This photo shows what the leaves on your plants look like, with a few starting to show the cut-outs.

As stormy mentioned, this is one individual plant so don't try to separate it. Be prepared for this to grow lots and perhaps even outgrow it's welcome. I've had to convince people not to buy this plant as they simply didn't have the room for it.

Comment: @ Jude, this is really wonderful information! I friend gave me this plant, it was almost dead, with just one little leaf. That was about a yr ago and since then this plant has taken off!!! Thankfully, I do have space for such a plant, both physically and mentally! I am excited to see this plant develop and grow!

Comment: I'm truly happy you have the room for it and love it! I've always wanted to have one and had many opportunities but not enough consistent light and DEFINITELY not the space for it. I'd love to know how your gets along.

Answer (score 3):

Probably Philodendron genus.  Yes, transplant that plant into a larger pot.  You've got what a 6" diameter pot there?  Go to 12" for this plant and its size.  Make sure you use only potting soil from a store. Drainage hole.  No rock or gravel below soil and above the drainage hole, lift bottom of pot up off surface with pieces of tile, rock or pot feet for best drainage.  Water when dry do not water until dry again.  Fertilize with Osmocote 14-14-14 twice per year not 4X.  As much sun as you can give it.

Do not try separating this plant.  This is but one plant and is normal.  The larger pot will make all better.

Comment: Thank you, Stormy. Should I prop up the stalks that are starting to droop due to their weight?

Comment: No, only add support for vegetables when they get heavy.  Otherwise, to support any plant to include trees is to weaken them.  Just like a cast on a broken arm.  Take if off and what do you see?  Muscular atrophy and a limb in need of exercise to get it back to what it used to be.  Philodendron is pretty much a vine plant.  You need to add direction, structures for this plant to use for growth expansion.  To stake it would be to weaken the main stem and not allow the main stem to be able to support the weight of leaves.  Not necessary. The weight causes thicker stronger stems.  Just like trees

Comment: The advice for these is either grow as a trailing plant, pinching out tips to keep it bushy, or to supply a moss stick or pole, and push the aerial  roots into that so its supported. You can make your own using a piece of chicken wire or clematis mesh, roll it to make a tube about 2 inches across, stuff it full of moss with a bamboo cane up the middle, and push the cane into your pot.

Comment: Good stuff, Bamboo.